# How do you translate from lambda terms to interaction nets?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus, interaction-nets

On [this paper](http://www.phil.uu.nl/~oostrom/publication/pdf/lambdascope.pdf), the author suggests a translation between lambda terms:

```
data Term = Zero | Succ Term | App Term Term | Lam Term
```

and interaction nets:

```
data Net = -- if I understood correctly
    Apply Net Net Net 
    | Abstract Net Net Net
    | Delete Net Net Int
    | Duplicate Net Net Net Int
    | Erase Net
```

Unfortunately I can not understand his compilation algorithm. It seems like the actual algorithm is missing, and I have no idea what he means with the images on the third page. I've tried understanding it by looking at the published source code, but the author defines it using his own graph rewriting DSL so I would have to learn it first. How exactly is the translation implemented as a normal Haskell function?

Comment: Yowzers! I'd tell you to post that on CS.SE, but sadly that site seems to get very little traffic, and to be even less focused than this one, so you may get a couple upvotes but no answers. Or I'd tell you to post on cs-theory.SE, but sadly you're likely to get nothing but downvotes there unless you're at least an upper-level graduate student.

Comment: Interaction nets are graphs, not trees. Your data type does not express this. -  The compilation (from Lambda to Net) is indeed given by Lambda to GLambda (Sect.1) and then the four diagrams above E. 4, then simplification (after Ex. 4). - Have you checked other papers by van Oostrom, e.g http://www.phil.uu.nl/~oostrom/oudonderwijs/cmitt/03-04/ (bottom of page), and the references, or other work by the authors that are cited, e.g., http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.9699

Comment: I am trying, but again, the pile of undefined things (probably assuming I should know) and the huge amount of big, different papers to read is, in general, is making this job very hard. I really think many would benefit from a brief summary and simple reference implementation, akin to that "implementing dependently typing" tutorial. Again, if anyone reading this is knowledgeable enough to provide this, please, consider doing so :)

Comment: Jan Rochel wrote an implementation of [lambdascope in haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graph-rewriting-lambdascope).

Comment: I know, thank you! I find the code quite complicated, though - it uses his own DSL so it is hard to see how it works. Plus, it is missing a "fromNet" function, so it is useless if all I want is normalizing terms. It has a great graphical interface, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an [implementation of interaction net reduction in Haskell](https://github.com/gergoerdi/interaction-nets/blob/master/src/Language/IntNet.hs) that uses `STRef`s to represent the net graph structure in a mutable way:

```
data NodeType = NRot
              | NLam
              | NApp
              | NDup Int
              | NEra
             deriving (Show)

type NodeID = Int
type Port s = STRef s (Node s, PortNum)

data Node s = Node
    { nodeType :: !NodeType
    , nodeID :: !NodeID
    , nodePort0, nodePort1, nodePort2 :: !(Port s)
    }
```

Conversion from lambda terms is implemented in a [separate module](https://github.com/gergoerdi/interaction-nets/blob/master/src/Language/IntNet/Lam.hs). It is not the nicest code I've ever written, because it's a straight transliteration of a [Javascript implementation](https://github.com/MaiaVictor/optlam) and I didn't really take the time to understand what the JS version is doing:

```
encodeLam :: Lam -> IntNet s (Node s)
encodeLam lam = do
    nextTag <- do
        ref <- lift $ newSTRef 0
        return $ lift $ do
            modifySTRef ref succ
            readSTRef ref

    let go scope up (Lam body) = do
            del <- mkNode NEra
            lam <- mkNode NLam
            linkHalf lam P0 up
            link (lam, P1) (del, P0)
            link (del, P1) (del, P2)
            bod <- go (lam:scope) (lam, P2) body
            linkHalf lam P2 bod
            return (lam, P0)
        go scope up (App f e) = do
            app <- mkNode NApp
            linkHalf app P2 up
            linkHalf app P0 =<< go scope (app, P0) f
            linkHalf app P1 =<< go scope (app, P1) e
            return (app, P2)
        go scope up (Var v) = do
            let lam = scope !! v
            (target, targetPort) <- readPort lam P1
            case nodeType target of
                NEra -> do
                    linkHalf lam P1 up
                    return (lam, P1)
                _ -> do
                    dup <- mkNode . NDup =<< nextTag
                    linkHalf dup P0 (lam, P1)
                    linkHalf dup P1 up
                    link (dup, P2) =<< readPort lam P1
                    linkHalf lam P1 (dup, P0)
                    return (dup, P1)

    root <- asks root
    enc <- go [] (root, P0) lam
    linkHalf root P0 enc
    return root
```

It also implements the reverse transformation:

```
decodeLam :: Node s -> IntNet s Lam
decodeLam root = do
    (setDepth, getDepth) <- do
        ref <- lift $ newSTRef mempty
        let set node depth = lift $ modifySTRef ref $
                             IntMap.insertWith (\ _new old -> old) (nodeID node) depth
            get node = lift $ (! nodeID node) <$> readSTRef ref
        return (set, get)

    let go depth exit (node, port) = do
            setDepth node depth
            case nodeType node of
                NDup _ -> do
                    let (port', exit') = case port of
                            P0 -> (head exit, tail exit)
                            _ -> (P0, port:exit)
                    go depth exit' =<< readPort node port'
                NLam -> case port of
                    P1 -> do
                        depth' <- getDepth node
                        return $ Var (depth - depth' - 1)
                    _ -> Lam <$> (go (succ depth) exit =<< readPort node P2)
                NApp -> do
                    f <- go depth exit =<< readPort node P0
                    e <- go depth exit =<< readPort node P1
                    return $ App f e
    go 0 [] =<< readPort root P0
```